# how to stop entering of username and password every time the activity started?

Tags: android

I need to store user-name and password , successfully authenticated the login buy storing the user-name and password in database but every time i start the activity again i need to again reenter the user-name and password .How to stop this from occurring (i.e i need to implement similar to sessions)?
thanks

Comment: You can try to store authenticated flag in shared preference.

Comment: on your splash screen/loginscreen just check your username and password is present or not. if there just skip to home screen else show login activity.

Answer (score 2):

Its damn simple ,if you were do some go ogling then you will get easily.

```
        //Save password
    SharedPreferences share=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor edit=share.edit();
    edit.putString("name","usernameValue");
    edit.putString("pass","passwordValue");
    edit.commit();


    //GetPassword  wherever you want when application open next time
    SharedPreferences share1=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String name=share1.getString("name", "");
    String pass=share1.getString("pass", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using web service then when you do login first time you will get session id from cookies that you can use in future to validate the user login status

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPref it is helpful to u when u get shared pref. value as not null then start next activity after login...